# Nodejs how to prevent a module from crashing (crypto)

Tags: node.js, error-handling, module

I use a module to encrypt/decrypt datas.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt(text){
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc','secret key');
    var encrypted = cipher.update(text.toString(),'utf8','hex') + cipher.final('hex');
    return encrypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc','secret key');
    var decrypted = decipher.update(text.toString(),'hex','utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
    return decrypted ;
}

module.exports.encrypt = encrypt;
module.exports.decrypt = decrypt;
```

And load it in my route :

```
var crypt = require('./middleware/encrypt');
var id = 10;

var id_crypted = crypt.encrypt(id);
console.log(id_crypted);
var id_decrypted = crypt.decrypt(id_crypted);
console.log(id_decrypted);
```

So this works fine (except i had to use text.toString() in the crypt module otherwise it crashes..).

The problem is on the decrypt. 
i have no control on the data that will be decrypted (i'm taking them from a cookie).

If for example i want to decrypt the value "10" then all my app crashes because the decrypt function throw an error about wrong final block length.

So how do i prevent my module from crashing all my app when there is an error ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the problematic function call in a try-catch block.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
});
```

Taken from [NodeJS docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

Comment: Thanks. Where do I need to put it on my app.js?

Comment: Anywhere in the startup script should do it. Recommend putting it in the bottom, that way you don't have to keep scrolling by it.

Comment: Note that uncaughtException is a very crude mechanism for exception handling and may be removed in the future. I dont think it's a good solution